# EF DataAnnotations two one to many relationships

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, data-annotations, entity-framework-migrations

How would I go about making this relationship in EF Code First without using Fluent API and only Using Data Annotations. I can only get it to make a one to one relationship.
Thanks.
(not enough rep for image https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqi5Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is currently no way to do this. I ended up adding NotMapped attribute to the properties and adding keys manually via migration up.